# Find All the bool variables from .aspx file by Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, pattern-matching

I want to get all the Boolean variables from a give aspx or cs file by using c# Regex,

Can any one tell me how can i do it. any hint

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks for your response, but if i have script block in aspx page like <% bool isvalid; %> then it is not working.

Comment: Try this. bool[\s]*([^\s]*)

Comment: have you got the correctregex?

Comment: It is not working for this code  <B>public bool isvalid, flag1 = true, flag2 = false;</B>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether or not you need to capture every flag individually something like this might get the job done:

```
bool\s*([^;]+);
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i find only global variables within a class of namespace